# Differentiating between users' cities

Tags: algorithm, web-applications, geolocation, ip

Say I have a collection of users, and I want to check if users are in two different cities based on their ip address.

Do I actually have to keep a database mapping IP group -> City? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I'm not concerned *which* cities the users are from, just the question of whether they're from *different* cities. And it doesn't have to be totally exact either, I'd be comfortable with a high percentage chance of the users being in different cities.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define high percentage?  If you wanted, you could use the following map http://xkcd.com/195/ to help you figure out if they're even on the same continent...